# How to prove that arithmetic progression contains non coprime pairs

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There is a progression $a_n=1+bn$. Prove that there is at least one pair $(a_i,a_j)$ such as $\gcd(a_i, a_j) \neq 1$.

When the $a_0$ is not |1|, it quite easy to prove:
$$a_{|a|} = a_0 + |a_0|b$$
$$\gcd(a_0, a_0 + |a_0|b) \geq |a_0|$$
But when the $a_0$ is |1|, I don't know how to play with it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: **Hint.** Try actually writing out the series for small values of $b$.  What is the smallest pair when $b = 2$?  What about when $b = 3$?  Or $b = 4$?  You should see a fairly obvious pattern.  Then see if you can prove it.  ¶ The tendency can be to try to do everything symbolically right off the bat.  Sometimes that works.  But if you get stuck, you should actually (as you say) "play with it" a little—just more concretely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_1=1+b$ and $a_{b+2}=1+b(b+2)=1 +b^2+2b=(1+b)^2$

$\text{GCD}(a_1,a_{b+2})=b+1$ therefore there is at least a pair of non coprime elements of the arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n\ne \pm 1$ then $a_n$ is divisible by a prime $p,$  so $a_{(n+p)}=a_n+bp$ is also divisible by $p.$